# Magnolia author instance does not work

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I have installed Magnolia CMS 5.0 pretty much successfully. My Author instance works perfectly fine. However, my public instance throws the following error which I don't know how to interpret. Anyone with an idea? Thanks a lot![image]

Comment: Can you put log file from the installation on pastebin.com or similar service and post link to it here? I'm sure there's more info in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of idea, if this is a unix system, check your open file limit.  `ulimit -n` Increase that by doing something like this `ulimit -n 2048` but put whatever number you want.  I got a lot of random errors when first installing Magnolia and this got me past a bunch of them.  That probably wont fix it to be honest.

Your problem looks like you are installing both instances on the same computer.  Make sure you have them seperated into clearly defined folder structure and not installing them into the same folders.  Otherwise, post more info like log files and steps you took to get here.  This post doesn't provide much to help you.